# Whose face is in the Doctor Who Christmas special intro?

Tags: doctor-who, character-identification

Does anyone know whose face this is:

[image]

I thought I saw another face but I couldn't find it again when I was taking snapshots.

Comment: After looking at it for a bit I think it's Matt Smith. Anyone have sources/info about other faces and why they're there?

Comment: What names appear immediately before/after the face?

Comment: I guess the "problem" here is the background. Those bright clouds above the head blend with it and it seems to be his hears (despite that being wrong).

Comment: Saw that episode just now and it's indeed been Matt Smith to me. It's just the cloud looking like hair.

Comment: To me it looks a little bit like Matt Smith with the first lot of ageing make-up on, but that could just be an illusion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is Matt Smith, the 11th Doctor. Here's a better screen shot:

[image]

In the classic series, the doctor's face always used to appear in the title sequence. See this [article](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Title_sequence) for details.

Some examples:

6th:
[image]

7th:
[image]

Comment: Not ‘always’; I see no faces in the first season.

Answer (score 3):

When I saw it first I thought or was the 6th doctor, but think it's Matt Smith, makes no sense otherwise.

Comment: As mentioned in the question's comments, I think it's just misleading: It is Matt Smith, but the bright clouds could be misinterpreted as the hairs of #6.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same face that has been appearing in every credit sequence during the 11th doctor's reign:  Matt Smith's. It's hard to make out but it's been there all along, people.

Comment: Not every, the face (of Smith) appeared for the first time in *the Snowmen*, the 2012 Christmas Special. See http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Title_Sequence#2012_-_present